# fprintf print chars and num with no loops

Tags: matlab, printf

I'm trying to use fprintf to write a data file. Say I have a matrix containing data like this:

```
Values = [ 1,  735123.0, 23, 24, 25;
           2,  735123.5, 34, 35, 36;
           ...
           8000, 739122.5, 21, 22, 43]
```

I can write that to a file using:

```
fprintf(FileID, '%d, %f, %d, %d, %d', Values')
```

But really that second column represents dates (datestr(735123.5) = 11-Sep-2012 12:00:00) and I'd like fprintf to print dates in the second column of the data file, so that the file will read

```
1, 11-Sep-2012 00:00:00, 23, 24, 25
2, 11-Sep-2012 12:00:00, 34, 35, 36
...
8000, 24-Aug-2023 12:00:00, 21, 22, 43
```

My matrix is thousands of lines long so I'd prefer not to have to loop through line by line.

Any suggestions how to procede?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
n = num2cell(Values');
n(2,:) = cellfun(@datestr, n(2, :),'UniformOutput', false);
fprintf(FileID, '%d, %s, %d, %d, %d', n{:});
```

Although `cellfun` is basically a loop.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was trying mat2cell and that wasn't working. cellfun seems quick enough compared to my loop. Or maybe it was the 'UniformOutput' part.

Comment: Also, for future reference, I've used '@(x) datestr(x, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')' rather than '@datestr' in order to ensure the output of time for midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Without `for` loops or `cellfun`:

```
separator = repmat(', ',size(Values,1),1); %// column used as separator
lineFeeds = repmat('\n',size(Values,1),1); %// column of line feeds
string = [ num2str((Values(:,1))) ...
           separator ...
           datestr(Values(:,2)) ...
           separator ...
           num2str(Values(:,3)) ...
           separator ...
           num2str(Values(:,4)) ...
           separator ...
           num2str(Values(:,5)) ...
           lineFeeds ];
string = reshape(string.',1,[]); %'// put everything in one row
FileID = fopen('tmp.txt', 'wt'); %// use 't', or '\n' may not get written to file
fprintf(FileID, string);
fclose(FileID);
```